# My laravel .env file config is downloadable via ip address! How to solve this on litespeed server?

Tags: laravel, security

hello I am creating a new laravel project with Openlitespeed server and I saw a glaring security issue.
I've added the following rule to the .htaccess of the site root and it works fine by stopping when someone tries to download the .env file by [www.mywebsite.com/.env](http://www.mywebsite.com/.env)
But to my surprise, it is possible to download the .env file easily by accessing the server IP, eg: 127.0.0.1/.env

```
    <Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    </Files>
```

how do I solve this? I have access to edit httpd_config.conf

Comment: You have misconfigured your server; it sounds like you have another virtual server with a document root in your app directory. Server configuration is a question better asked at [webmasters.se] or [sf]. Why are you not using Nginx or Apache which are both well supported and extensively documented for use with Laravel?

Comment: Your web server's docroot should point to the Laravel `public/` directory, so that only the files in that directory are exposed.